# Cinlar Ex. 1.15: Trace space of a measurable space.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In constructing the trace space on a subset of a measurable space, it seems one has to assume that the subset is an element of the original measure space's sigma algebra, i.e., measurable in the original measure space. This is not explicitly given in the problem statement.
I have not found a list of errata for this book anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of trace $\sigma$-algebra can be defined even if the set does not belong to the original $\sigma$-algebra. If $(X,\mathcal F)$ is a measurable space and $A\subset X$, then the trace  $\sigma$-algebra is defined by 
$$\mathcal F_A:=\{A\cap S,S\in\mathcal F\} $$
and this is a $\sigma$-algebra on $A$ even if $A\notin\mathcal F$.